# How to restore trained model and calculate test accuracy in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have trained my CNN model and stored it in directory named `model` which contains files as shown below

```
\model
|--- checkpoint
|--- model.data-00000-of-00001
|--- model.index
|--- model.meta
```

I want to restore the model and calculate the test accuracy for that I am using the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import glob

images    = []
labels    = []
img_names = []
cls       = []

test_path = 'data\\cifar-10\\test'
image_size = 32
num_channels    = 3

# Prepare input data
with open('data\\cifar-10\\wnids.txt') as f:
    classes = f.readlines()
classes = [x.strip() for x in classes] 

num_classes = len(classes)

for fields in classes:   
    index = classes.index(fields)
    print('Read {} files (Index: {})'.format(fields, index))
    path = os.path.join(test_path, fields, '*g')
    files = glob.glob(path)
    for fl in files:
        image = cv2.imread(fl)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (image_size, image_size),0,0, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        image = image.astype(np.float32)
        image = np.multiply(image, 1.0 / 255.0)
        images.append(image)
        label = np.zeros(len(classes))
        label[index] = 1.0
        labels.append(label)
        flbase = os.path.basename(fl)
        img_names.append(flbase)
        cls.append(fields)

images    = np.array(images)
labels    = np.array(labels)
img_names = np.array(img_names)
cls       = np.array(cls)

session = tf.Session()
tf_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model\\model.meta')
tf_saver.restore(session, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('model'))

x      = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, image_size, image_size, num_channels], name='x')
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes], name='y_true')
y_true_cls = tf.argmax(y_true, axis=1)

y_pred     = tf.nn.softmax(layer_fc2, name='y_pred')
y_pred_cls = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(y_pred_cls, y_true_cls)
accuracy           = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

feed_dict_test  = {x: images, y_true: labels}

test_acc = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict_test)

msg     = "Test Accuracy: {1:>6.1%}"
print(msg.format(test_acc))
```

On running the above code I'm getting the error

> NameError: name 'layer_fc2' is not defined

How can I properly restore the model and calculate the test accuracy?

Comment: Don't you have to create the fc layer before using it?

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layer_fc2` is a python variable defined in your training script (where you define the graph) and it's not present here. What you need to do is to find this layer. Unfortunately, you didn't name it in train time. Change your `create_fc_layer` code to

```
def create_fc_layer(input, num_inputs, num_outputs, name, use_relu=True):
  weights = create_weights(shape=[num_inputs, num_outputs])
  biases = create_biases(num_outputs)
  layer = tf.matmul(input, weights) + biases
  if use_relu:
    layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)

  return tf.identity(layer, name=name)  # return a named layer

...

layer_fc2   = create_fc_layer(input=layer_fc1, num_inputs=fc_layer_size, num_outputs=num_classes, name='layer_fc2', use_relu=False)
```

After this in your new script:

```
layer_fc2 = session.graph.get_operation_by_name('layer_fc2')
```

By the way, you also don't need to redefine `y_pred`, `y_pred_cls`, etc. Give them names and simply get it from the restored graph.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am getting following error after making changes as you suggested

`KeyError: "The name 'layer_fc2' refers to an Operation not in the graph."`

Comment: Right. I suppose you didn't retrain the model. So the model you have right now doesn't have a name for `layer_fc2`. It gets some internal name, something like 'Relu:0'. You can try to use this, but it's error-prone. I suggest you change your training script, *retrain* a new model, where the required operations are named properly, and use it

Comment: I have re-trained the model after making the changes as you have suggested. But still the same error.

Comment: What does `session.graph.get_operations()` tell? Also try `layer_fc2:0`

Comment: I tried changing `layer_fc2` to `layer_fc2:0`. Now I'm getting this error `ValueError: Name 'layer_fc2:0' appears to refer to a Tensor, not a Operation.`

Comment: @OliviaBrown Ah, I got it. You don't have a `relu` activation in the second FC layer, that's why it doesn't get a name. Please see an update to my answer.

Comment: Now error `TypeError: Can't convert Operation 'layer_fc2' to Tensor (target dtype=None, name=None, as_ref=False)`